# JMeter - Https Test Script Recorder is not recording locally hosted webpages(Localhost)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Am new to JMeter. Trying to record the steps in JMeter. I have the following settings.

HTTP Request Defaults:

[image: HTTP Request Defaults]

HTTPS Test Script Recorder
[image: HTTPS Test Script Recorder]

Proxy Settings
[image: Proxy Settings]

After all these been set, started the recorder and launched my http://localhost:81/WebPages/ and start performing actions but none of my steps are recorded.

Also tried JMeter chrome extension - Blazemeter even that is not recording localhost webpages actions.Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me now! I installed the JMeter certificate which is in the bin folder again to make sure it installed fine and also removed the Proxy exception  (localhost,127.0.0.1) that I had in the settings and that solved my problem. 
[image]